# Dash - Callback with 2 input

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have 2 dropdown list and one text area.
I need the text area to accept input from both drop-down lists indiscriminately (one at a time, according to which the user select), but display only the last value selected (evry time i select a value from one of the two dropdown, it overwrite the last one selected).

How do I write the callback?

I thought I could simply write:

```
@app.callback(
Output(component_id='text_output', component_property='value'),
Input(component_id='lista_file_mt', component_property='value'),
Input(component_id='lista_file_crt', component_property='value'))
```

But, obviously, it doesn't work

Comment: You're right, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Dynamic text output concatenates `multi=True` dropdown options

Something like this?:

```py
import dash

from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash import no_update
from dash.dependencies import Input
from dash.dependencies import Output


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="dropdown-1",
            options=[
                {"label": "a", "value": "a"},
                {"label": "b", "value": "b"},
                {"label": "c", "value": "c"},
            ],
            multi=True,
        ),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="dropdown-2",
            options=[
                {"label": "d", "value": "d"},
                {"label": "e", "value": "e"},
                {"label": "f", "value": "f"},
            ],
            multi=True,
        ),
        html.Div(id="textarea-1", children=[]),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("textarea-1", "children"),
    [Input("dropdown-1", "value"), Input("dropdown-2", "value")],
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_text_input(dd1, dd2):
    text = []
    if dd1:
        text += ["".join(dd1)]
    if dd2:
        text += ["".join(dd2)]
    return text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image: example of app]

## Dynamic text outputs only single value indiscriminately from any present dropdowns

Alright, this is a tiny bit more complex, requiring the use of `dcc.Store`, to be able to discern when a dropdown has been changed, which one is it which has a new value that differs from the value currently already [last] displayed.

```py
import sys

import dash
from dash import html
from dash import dcc
from dash import no_update
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Store(id="session", storage_type="session"),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="dropdown-1",
            options=[
                {"label": "a", "value": "a"},
                {"label": "b", "value": "b"},
                {"label": "c", "value": "c"},
            ],
            placeholder="Choose a value",
            value=None,
        ),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="dropdown-2",
            options=[
                {"label": "d", "value": "d"},
                {"label": "e", "value": "e"},
                {"label": "f", "value": "f"},
            ],
            placeholder="Choose a value",
            value=None,
        ),
        html.Div(id="textarea-1", children=[]),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    [Output("textarea-1", "children"), Output("session", "data")],
    [Input("dropdown-1", "value"), Input("dropdown-2", "value")],
    State("session", "data"),
    # prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_text_input(dd1, dd2, data):
    print(dd1, dd2, data, file=sys.stderr)
    if not data:
        print(dd1, dd2, data, file=sys.stderr)
        return no_update, {"dd1": None, "dd2": None}
    if dd1 and (dd1 != data["dd1"]):
        return [dd1], {"dd1": dd1, "dd2": data["dd2"]}
    if dd2 and (dd2 != data["dd2"]):
        return [dd2], {"dd1": data["dd1"], "dd2": dd2}

    return no_update, data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image: app knows which latest dropdown to display-1]
[image: app knows which latest dropdown to display-2]

Comment: I would recommend using a regular old Div over the `html.Textarea` component, if I understand what you're trying to do correctly

Comment: Hello John, thank you for your answer. 
Following your example, I don't want multiple selection (like a and c in the first dropdown). I want to select 'a' from first dropdown and see 'a' in the div below. Then, if later I select 'c' from the second dropdown, I want only 'c' in the div; if again, I select another value, only the last one must be displayed. 
I hope I've been clear

Comment: No prob — I'm trying to practice Dash myself. I've updated my answer, I see what you meant now. The new code should work! Lmk

Comment: Ok great! 
Last one (if you want I add a new question): if I want the value of the picklist as a filter for a dataframe, so that I can return this:
def insert_text(id_text):
    
    if id_text:
        return df_testi_lem[df_testi_lem['id_text']==id_text].values[0][0],

where id_text is the value of picklist

Comment: If you wouldn't mind upvoting the answer here and making that a new question, and posing the question fully adequately (I just mean fully clearly so no one marks it as closed or as a non-unique question, etc.), I can def help ya out with it 

Comment: Ok thanks john. I'll create a new question, but now it says me I've reached my question limit. Could you pleas pass me the new code and as soon as possible I'll post my new question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238586/discussion-between-nick9214-and-john-collins).